# PHP Include Variables

Tags: php, variables

I've created those two files, but it doesn't work, could you please correct my code? I am newbie in PHP, so please don't blame me... Thanks in advace!

Final file:

```
<?php 
include 'template.php';

$show = "The Flash";
$episode_name = "Pilot";

$season = "01";
$episode = "01";
?>
```

Template:

```
<?php echo $show; ?>
```

Comment: Be kind and explain __what is not working__.

Comment: Which template system? If plain PHP, `echo $show`.

Comment: @panther and at least __after__ `$show` is defined.

Comment: You __cannot__ output value of a variable __before__ you set it's value.

Comment: It's plain php.

Comment: DId you define $show variable first

Comment: you are including `template.php` in `final.php` when you should actually be including `final.php` in `template.php`.

Answer (score -1):

Try including after?

```
<?php 

$show = "The Flash";
$episode_name = "Pilot";

$season = "01";
$episode = "01";

include 'template.php';
?>
```

On my server I did:
index.php

```
<?php
  $title = "Test";
  $template = "./template.php";
  include $template;
?>
```

template.php

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

It worked perfectly fine. It echo'ed "Test"